# JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface unsecure in jboss 7.1.1.Final

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

When i try to deploy my application (JSF, Primefaces and EJB) in JBoss7.1.1.Final, the deployment failed and showing the following error messages.

```
15:07:54,373 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.network.unsecure: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.unsecure: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface unsecure
            at org.jboss.as.server.services.net.NetworkInterfaceService.start(NetworkInterfaceService.java:97) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_91]

15:07:54,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
15:07:54,464 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
15:07:54,489 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
15:07:54,531 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
15:07:54,841 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
15:08:00,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)   JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public
  service jboss.network.unsecure: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.unsecure: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface unsecure
  service jboss.network.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.management: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface management
```

the port is automatically (8080) closing.
Anyone have any idea what is the problem.

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <!--
          ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
          ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL 
          -->
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made any changes to `standalone.xml` or `standalone.conf` to set a new bind address? In that case, you will most probably need to create a loopback entry in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo:1`.

Check this link for details:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/222677?tstart=0&_sscc=t

Comment: could you please check the entries for <interfaces> in your standalone.xml and paste the contents here?

Comment: added, can you please check it now.

Comment: The entries look fine. Though i am a bit confused as to the comments in the standalone.xml . They usually get overwritten when you run the server. As to another issue that leads to this problem is the etc/hosts file. check the ip address in that file.