# Failed to resolve interface public in jboss in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, webserver, jboss7.x, redhat

I am working on JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final in amazon EC2 ( redhat server ) server. I changed my ip 127.0.0.1 to 52.32.0.197 ( public EC2 server ip ) whenever i am running my Jboss it is throwing :
`Services which failed to start:service jboss.network.public:org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public`

After googling i change my entries in "**/etc/hosts**" which is currently look like

```
52.32.0.197 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 ocalhost4.localdomain4
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Again i got this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372110/jbas015810-failed-to-resolve-interface-unsecure-in-jboss-7-1-1-final) and change my "**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo**" to

```
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=52.32.0.197
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
NETWORK=127.0.0.0
# If you're having problems with gated making 127.0.0.0/8 a martian,
# you can change this to something else (255.255.255.255, for example)
BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback-1
```

but still getting same error, please help me to resolve this ?

My standalone.xml contains

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:52.32.0.197}"/>
        </interface>
        <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <!--
              ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
              ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL 
              -->
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

Comment: `NETWORK=127.0.0.0` is incorrect.  Check out this URL :  https://developer.jboss.org/thread/222677

Comment: What it should be according to you? it is same as given in above url

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with JBOSS, but this is clearly a bad IP binding problem.

First, you must have a valid IP Address.  I am surprise you didn't mentioned error throw by OS. Your public IP address cannot sit on a wrong network.

```
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=52.32.0.197
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=52.32.0.0
```

Then come to the binding, as point out in the link [JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/222677)

> This kind of error could occur if you happen to have specified bind
>   address for `JAVA_OPTS` in your configs in `standalone.conf`
>   -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.xxx.xxx -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.xxx.xxx -Djboss.bind.address.unsecure=192.168.xxx.xxx

open `standalone.conf` and change those IP address you see (should be 127.0.0.1) to 52.32.0.197. Restart.

Comment: nowhere this "-Djboss.bind.address" is mentioned in standalone.conf file.

Comment: I tried by changing IP in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo file but still same exception is coming.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i have resolved that by updating my firewall settings ,Which blocked the public IP access to the application